# SMSManger not sending message with apostrophe in it

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am using this code to send messages:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    Log.d("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    Log.d("Message", message);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, new Intent(
            mContext, Object.class), 0);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
}
```

It is not sending the messages with apostrophe. Here are the messages I tested:

1. Sorry, busy right now with a live person. I’ll contact you when I’m free.
2. Sorry, busy right now with a live person. I will contact you when I am free.
3. '

1 and 3 didn;t worked. But 2 worked. (*yes... I sent only apostrophe in 3rd sms*). Pretty weird. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see some error messages in LogCat? It might well be that certain characters would have to be escaped.

Comment: @Ridcully No log printed. Just some log I manually printed.

Comment: @Ridcully I tried escaping apostrophe using \ and &#39; but didn't worked.

Comment: You might try using the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method, in case you're not actually using the character set you think you are. Also, what is your _sent_ `PendingIntent` meant to do?

Comment: @berserk No problem! Glad to help. I also wanted to mention that, unless you have an Activity subclass named `Object`, I don't think your PendingIntent is going to do anything. You can pass null for that, too, by the way, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send Apostrophe in SMS you have to use the escape character for an apostrophe. Putting a backslash character followed by a quote ( \" or \' ) will work.

In this case, your string should look like this "Sorry, busy right now with a live person. I\'ll contact you when I\'m free."

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply. It's a very old question and I was able to solve it with @Mike M.'s comment. I won't be able to test this now, but I hope it works.